# How to show font awesome icons in ngModel value : angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a font awesome icon inside an anchor tag and a input type text field. When clicking on that anchor tag i want to show that icon in the input field's model value. Is it possible? Like commenting someone and add some similes with the comment.

Also if submit the form can I store the entire value in the database?

**Component HTML -**

```
<div class="stories-content">
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputval">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="setEmoji()">
      <span style="width: 30px; height: 30px;display: block;" class="far fa-grin"></span>
   </a>
</div>
```

**Component.ts -**

```
setEmoji(){
    this.inputval = //What To do
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/) of fontawesome. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-58lbkc)

change font family of input to show icon in input

```
input{
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

and use cheatsheat code  as input value

```
<div class="stories-content">
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputval">
   <a (click)="setEmoji('&#xf118;')">
      <i class="fa fa-smile"></i> 
   </a>
</div>
```

and if you want to show this in somewhere you need to change its fontfamily also to show icon again

Comment: Can I use multiple icons in the input and also on pressing backspace or delete can i be able to remove them?

Comment: I added in demo multiple example. You will increases buttons foreach icon and give its code in click event as parameter and ofcourse this is input you can delete it.

Comment: In demo I also added one evet that if you write :) then it converts to smile icon input it can be better that clicking

Answer (score 0):

Every Emoji will be associated with one unique Unicode code (Decimal or Hexa Decimal). In Order to use that code, you are supposed to map into the inner HTML value like below.

```
<div class="stories-content">
   <textarea [innerHTML]=inputVal></textarea>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="setEmoji()">
      <span style="width: 30px; height: 30px;display: block;" class="far fa-grin"></span>
   </a>
</div>

import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  inputVal = '&#128514;&#128516;';
  setEmoji(){
    this.inputval = '&#128516;'; //What To do
}
}
```

you can find the some of the sample emoji codes : https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_smileys.asp

Comment: If i want to add multiple icons how i am going to append them , also can i use backspace to remove a icon?

Comment: yes you can. updated the answer with textarea scenario where by default you will see you emoji. you can remove them by using the backspace as well

Comment: one last thing I want to ask can i add some text in the text area? simple text Ex: happy birthday than a emoji?

Comment: Yes anything which you added in the ngmodel variable will be visible to the textarea along with the text and emoji.